# Redis inside a docker container on Windows Server 2016

Tags: linux, docker, redis, windows-server-2016

I have setup docker on Windows Server 2016. Now I have to get Redis image on Server 2016 but I am getting this error while pulling Redis image.

"**no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.14393 in the manifest list entries**"

I have tried setting experimental flag to True but of no use.

How can I resolve the issue. Either I can install Redis on Windows Server 2016 or not?

Answer (score 2):

The perfect alternative for Redis on Windows is Memurai. I've been using it for a long time. Completely satisfied with the product!

Comment: You can download Memurai Developer Edition for free from memurai.com.

Comment: Simon, Actually I need to upgrade to latest version of Redis due to some vulnerabilities in older version. Which version of Memurai are you using? Is there any issue did you face with it?